# Passing control back to a Backbone Router from a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a loginview and its loginmodel. loginmodel is created from the initialize of the mainrouter. this way according to the loginmodel's loginp attribute mainrouter's `render_home` decides whether to render homeview or navigate to login route which calls `render_login`. `render_login` have a method to `save()`  the loginmodel populated from the loginview's input fields. So if the data is correct `save()` responded and loginmodel changes, its loginp attribute becomes true. so now the homeview should be rendered. but I cannot success this.

I think at this point the control should be passed back to the mainrouter's route that invokes `render_home` above again. So it tests `loginView.model.get('loginp') == true` and results in true so this time creates homeview and renders it via `homeView.render()` defined in the homeview already.

I put a listenTo in the loginview for when its model changes or syncs to call route in mainrouter to  call render_home. but this ends in endless back and forths between these two view without any render. `this.listenTo( this.loginView.model, 'sync', Backbone.history.navigate("",{trigger:true}));`

route `""` is assigned to `render_home` by the way.

What am I missing. Is it not possible to pass control back to a router?
main router:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ratchet',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'login/loginmodel',

    'login/loginview',
    'register/registerview',

    'home/homeview',
    ],
    function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, LoginModel, LoginView, RegisterView, HomeView){
        var MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "": "render_home",

                "login": "render_login",
                "register": "render_register"
            },

            initialize: function(){
                this.loginView = new LoginView;                 
            },

            render_home: function(){                    
                this.loginView.model.fetch({
                    success: function(model){
                        if( model.get('loginp') == true ){ //show you app view for logged in users!
                            this.homeView = new HomeView();
                            this.homeView.render();
                        }
                        else { //not logged in!
                            Backbone.history.navigate("/login", {trigger:true})
                        }
                    },
                });

            },
            render_login: function(){ //display your login view
                this.loginView.render();

            },
            render_register: function(){ //display your register view
                this.registerView = new RegisterView;                   
                this.registerView.render();
            },
        });

        return MainRouter;
});
```

loginview:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'ratchet',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'login/loginmodel',
    'text!login/logintemplate.html',

    ],
    function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, LoginModel, LoginTemplate){
        var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

            el: $('body'),

            initialize: function(){
                this.model = new LoginModel;
            },

            template: _.template( LoginTemplate ),

            render: function(){ //display your login view
                this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );
            },

            events: {
                'keyup input' : 'updateform',
                'click #loginbutton' : 'login',
                'click #renderregisterbutton' : 'render_register',
            },

            updateform: function(e){
                var el = e.target;
                var formData = {};
                formData[ el.id ] = $(el).val();
                this.model.set( formData );
            },

            login: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.model.save();
                console.log( JSON.stringify( this.model ) );
            },

            render_register: function(){
                Backbone.history.navigate("/register", {trigger:true});
            },
        });

        return LoginView;
});
```

loginmodel:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone) {
        var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            urlRoot: '/log_in',

            defaults: {
                username: null,
            },
        });

        return LoginModel;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can "pass control" from a `Route` to a  `View` and back; your `render_login` function does exactly that:

```
render_login: function(){ //display your login view
    // 1) router has control
    this.loginView.render(); // 2) control passes to loginView
    // 3) control passes back to the router
},
```

But that only works with *synchronous* logic.  I think the problem you're having is because you are using *asynchronous* logic (`this.loginView.model.fetch()`) inside your `render_home` method.  Asynchronous logic splits off from the main execution path, so the path for `render_home` is more like:

```
// 0) Router has control, and calls render_home
render_home: function(){
    // 1) LoginView has control
    this.loginView.model.fetch({
        success: function(model){
            // 4) LoginView has control once again, but now routing is done
            if( model.get('loginp') == true ){ //show you app view for logged in users!
                this.homeView = new HomeView();
                this.homeView.render();
            }
            else { //not logged in!
                Backbone.history.navigate("/login", {trigger:true})
            }
        },
    });
    // 2) LoginView still has control
},
// 3) Control passes back to the Router, which finishes routing
```

So, by the time the `fetch` returns, there is no routing logic to come back to.

However, this is easy enough to fix: just call `Backbone.history.navigate` (with `trigger: true`) from your `fetch` success handler.  This will start a new routing process, and by that point (since the `fetch` has completed) the `LoginModel` will now be populated and your routing logic should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It has given me insights about control pass. When I have added the navigate you suggested it caused endless back and forth between two views. Now I have solved it. I will write when I am complete. It includes in router a `this.listenTo( this.loginView.model, 'change', this.render_home );//this solved render_home problem.`

Comment: Ah, sorry my solution didn't work "out of the box" (sometimes it can be hard to write code for StackOverflow without an IDE/test environment).  When you have the final solution you can either: A) post it as a separate answer, B) edit my answer and add the new code, or C) (if you don't have edit permissions) add the new code as a comment and I'll be happy to update my answer with it.